# Multi-parts nodes in a matrix with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

Good evening (or morning, as you wish) everyone

I am using tikz and I encounter some little annoyance while using multi-parts nodes in a matrix.
It may be trivial but I cannot find out why using multi-parts nodes in a matrix gets me some additionnal row :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart, fit,backgrounds}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {
        shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2}]

  \node[matrix,draw,align=center]
  {\node{
  \nodepart{one}coucou
  \nodepart{two}double coucou};&\node{recoucou};\\};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks for any explanation

Comment: You defined, that `ęvery node` is multi part node. Your image show exactly what you define.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is caused by your `matrix`-shaped node being, well, another node, so your `every node/.style` also applies to it. Either define a style for the multipart nodes and apply it to them or redefine the shape for the matrix, or use the `nodes` option for the matrix:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart, fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style = {
        shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2}]
  \node[matrix,draw,align=center,shape=rectangle,]
  {\node{\nodepart{one}coucou\nodepart{two}double coucou};&\node{recoucou};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[mynode/.style = {
        shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2}]
  \node[matrix,draw,align=center]
  {\node[mynode]{\nodepart{one}coucou\nodepart{two}double coucou};&\node[mynode]{recoucou};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[matrix,draw,align=center,nodes = {
        shape=rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2}]
  {\node{\nodepart{one}coucou\nodepart{two}double coucou};&\node{recoucou};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]